# Matching hyperlinked images using preg_match

Tags: preg-match

Been working on a preg_match expreesion to match a hyperlinked image.  Need to use preg_match because the data comes from a database and need to some alternations before rendering in html

This is my match experession but this won't do a match on the example hyperlink below.

```
  /<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*><img(.*)<\/a>/msU


 <a href="http://lifehacker.com/5936040/improvise-a-laptop-cooling-pad-with-plastic-bottle-caps"  caps"="" bottle="" plastic="" with="" pad"="" title="Click here to read Improvise a Laptop Cooling ">
```

Is there something wrong with the expression that I'm (obviously) not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: ok..just tried this simplified expression and this won't match either  /<a(.*)><img (.*)<\/a>/msU

Comment: What would you like to match ? The url/src or the whole tag ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If yes, please post the solution. BTW, the [regex you posted works](https://regex101.com/r/FNdhBu/1).